# Call the function in macros

Tags: vba, excel, code128

I added a function in the excel visual basic like below which converts the string in to the bar code got this from the [blog](https://code.adonline.id.au/easily-generate-code-128-barcodes-in-excel/)

[image]

```
   Public Function Code128(SourceString As String)

  Dim Counter As Integer
  Dim CheckSum As Long
  Dim mini As Integer
  Dim dummy As Integer
  Dim UseTableB As Boolean
  Dim Code128_Barcode As String

  If Len(SourceString) > 0 Then

    'Check for valid characters
    For Counter = 1 To Len(SourceString)

        Select Case Asc(Mid(SourceString, Counter, 1))

            Case 32 To 126, 203

            Case Else

                MsgBox "Invalid character in barcode string." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please only use standard ASCII characters", vbCritical
                Code128 = ""
                Exit Function

        End Select

    Next

    Code128_Barcode = ""
    UseTableB = True

    Counter = 1
    Do While Counter <= Len(SourceString)

        If UseTableB Then

            'Check if we can switch to Table C
            mini = IIf(Counter = 1 Or Counter + 3 = Len(SourceString), 4, 6)
            GoSub testnum

            If mini% < 0 Then 'Use Table C

                If Counter = 1 Then

                    Code128_Barcode = Chr(205)

                Else 'Switch to table C

                    Code128_Barcode = Code128_Barcode & Chr(199)

                End If

                UseTableB = False

            Else

                If Counter = 1 Then Code128_Barcode = Chr(204) 'Starting with table B

            End If

        End If

        If Not UseTableB Then

            'We are using Table C, try to process 2 digits
            mini% = 2
            GoSub testnum

            If mini% < 0 Then 'OK for 2 digits, process it

                dummy% = Val(Mid(SourceString, Counter, 2))
                dummy% = IIf(dummy% < 95, dummy% + 32, dummy% + 100)
                Code128_Barcode = Code128_Barcode & Chr(dummy%)
                Counter = Counter + 2

            Else 'We haven't got 2 digits, switch to Table B

                Code128_Barcode = Code128_Barcode & Chr(200)
                UseTableB = True

            End If

        End If

        If UseTableB Then

            'Process 1 digit with table B
            Code128_Barcode = Code128_Barcode & Mid(SourceString, Counter, 1)
            Counter = Counter + 1

        End If

    Loop

    'Calculation of the checksum
    For Counter = 1 To Len(Code128_Barcode)

        dummy% = Asc(Mid(Code128_Barcode, Counter, 1))
        dummy% = IIf(dummy% < 127, dummy% - 32, dummy% - 100)

        If Counter = 1 Then CheckSum& = dummy%

        CheckSum& = (CheckSum& + (Counter - 1) * dummy%) Mod 103

    Next

    'Calculation of the checksum ASCII code
    CheckSum& = IIf(CheckSum& < 95, CheckSum& + 32, CheckSum& + 100)

    'Add the checksum and the STOP
    Code128_Barcode = Code128_Barcode & Chr(CheckSum&) & Chr$(206)
End If

Code128 = Code128_Barcode

Exit Function


     testnum:

    'if the mini% characters from Counter are numeric, then mini%=0
    mini% = mini% - 1
    If Counter + mini% <= Len(SourceString) Then

        Do While mini% >= 0

            If Asc(Mid(SourceString, Counter + mini%, 1)) < 48 Or Asc(Mid(SourceString, Counter + mini%, 1)) > 57 Then Exit Do
            mini% = mini% - 1

        Loop

    End If

    Return

   End Function
```

I need to call this function in the macro I am creating for formating the cells.  I am new to macros and the vba function. Now I dont know how to call these function inside macros and pass the column A in to the function in a loop.So all the values in column A is converted in to bar codes

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
.PrintGridlines = True

.Orientation = xlLandscape
.PaperSize = xlPaperA4

 .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
 .FitToPagesTall = False

  End With

  For Each Target In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp))
   If Target <> "" Then
   With Range(Target, Target.Offset(0, 11))
   .WrapText = True
  End With
   End If
  Next
```

Comment: Think you need to post all your code. if you Google custom functions I'm sure you will find guidance on how to call.

Comment: @SJR I tried googling, not sure how to iterate over a column to call the function. Thats the reason I reached out here for help

Comment: OK well post the function code. Are you asking how to call it from the code that you have posted above?

Comment: The above is the macro. I will post the function code now

Comment: Are all the values in column A strings? Do you want them replaced with the result of passing them through the formula, or the results placed elsewhere?

Comment: You appear to have posted this question twice - please can you close the other one so people don't waste their time answering it?

Comment: I have deleted the other question. The column A is string currently but once I call the function I will have to set the font to Code128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "set the font to Code128" so this is my best guess

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintGridlines = True
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
End With

For Each Target In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
        Target.Value = Code128(Target.Value)
        Target.Resize(, 12).WrapText = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How can set the font style of column A

Comment: That's a different question. Looks like the link has instructions on how to install the font.

Comment: Ya i did install the font. But I am not sure how to set one column when `Target.Font = Code 128` it throws error

Comment: A guess but try Target.Font = "Code 128" or you could do manually as in step 7.

Comment: I am getting an runtime error 424  in the `Target.Value = Code128(Target.Value)`

Comment: You've marked this as an answer - does this mean that you have solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Code128(tempString)
```

Make sure Option Explicit is at the top of your function (may not be needed if you have a Public function, not sure)